# How to search value from serialized data n mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to search data which is stored in serialized form in this table.

Table Structure

[image]

For

meta_key - mgm_member_options

meta_value -

a:31:{s:2:"id";s:1:"1";s:13:"custom_fields";a:6:{s:10:"first_name";s:5:"Admin";s:9:"last_name";s:5:"Basil";s:7:"address";s:0:"";s:4:"city";s:0:"";s:5:"state";s:0:"";s:3:"zip";s:0:"";}s:22:"other_membership_types";a:0:{}s:12:"payment_info";a:0:{}s:6:"coupon";a:0:{}s:7:"upgrade";a:0:{}s:6:"extend";a:0:{}s:4:"code";s:10:"mgm_member";s:4:"name";s:10:"Member Lib";s:11:"description";s:10:"Member Lib";s:7:"setting";a:0:{}s:6:"saving";s:1:"1";s:8:"trial_on";s:1:"0";s:10:"trial_cost";s:1:"0";s:14:"trial_duration";s:1:"0";s:19:"trial_duration_type";s:1:"d";s:16:"trial_num_cycles";s:1:"0";s:8:"duration";s:1:"0";s:13:"duration_type";s:1:"m";s:6:"amount";s:1:"0";s:8:"currency";s:3:"USD";s:9:"join_date";s:0:"";s:13:"last_pay_date";s:0:"";s:11:"expire_date";s:0:"";s:15:"membership_type";s:5:"guest";s:6:"status";s:8:"Inactive";s:12:"payment_type";s:0:"";s:13:"autoresponder";s:0:"";s:10:"subscribed";s:0:"";s:9:"rss_token";s:32:"af8214c978dedcaa066bd8c223b7d22d";s:13:"user_password";s:16:"m9ROVxRwfxWwJzti";}

I want to find zip code.
How can do this using sql query?

Query that i am using

> if(isset($_GET['as_zip']) && !empty($_GET['as_zip'])){
>                     $as_zip = $_GET['as_zip'];
>                     array_push($meta_query_array, array('key' => 'mgm_member_options', 'value' => $as_zip, 'compare' => '='));
>                 }   // prepare arguments        $args  = array(             'role' => $role,        'number' => '10',       'orderby' => 'display_name',        'fields' =>
>   'all_with_meta',      'meta_query' => $meta_query_array       );

Comment: If finding a row by the zipcode is a common query, I would suggest refactoring the database to put the zipcode in its own column that can be indexed by the DBMS.  It will make the query run significantly faster.

Comment: Its wordpress and i do not want to do that .

Comment: Your example is not a query.  My suggestion is that if this is something you need to search by, it should be a field within MySQL.

Comment: @AjayPatel You can modify the database. It is not some sacred thing.  You would at least want to modify the meta_value field to have an index, or you are going to be having VERY inefficient searches.  The problem with what you are asking is knowing whether the serialized data is always going to have a common structure to where you can make a predictable search string.

Comment: @AjayPatel if you dont want to do that then you're going to have to pull the entire data set back into PHP and then reference the ['zip'] array member. I think that refactoring the db sounds more palatable than creating some search/filter code. Just imagine, pull the *entire* data set back, iterate through each row, checking to see if it's value for ['zip'] meets your criteria. Doesn't sound too efficient to me.

Comment: Sounds like photocopying every name in the phone book, one by one, then trying to find all the Smiths using OCR, one by one.

Comment: @All This is plugin default db structure not mine. I have to adjust to fact from this.